# Be a Lie group $\Longrightarrow$ smooth manifold?

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

I have a little doubt about Lie Groups. If $M$ is a topological manifold, and I can show that $M$ has a Lie group structure (and therefore a smooth manifold structure), and the group operations are continuous with respect to the underlying topology of the topological manifold structure, does this imply that the topological manifold structure on $M$ is equivalent to the smooth manifold structure?

Is there some counter example for this?

Comment: Why wouldn't it?  Isn't every Lie group a smooth manifold?

Comment: So if I have a manifold and I must to prove tha this manifold is a smooth manifold.  I just need to show it's a Lie group, rigth?

Comment: I now understand your question and have edited it to clarify what I think you want to know.

Comment: I guess there could be a question about whether the _continuity_ of the group operations inescapably implies their _smoothness_...

Comment: Your question is unclear. When you say "If  is a topological manifold, and I can show that  has a Lie group structure" - do you mean that $M$ as a set has a Lie group structure or that $M$ as a topological space has a Lie group structure? In the second case, there is nothing to be proven.

Comment: ... while in the 1st case, there are counter-examples, although, not among simple real Lie groups.

Answer (score 4):

A Lie Group is defined to be a smooth manifold which is also a group with compatible group operations. So a Lie Group is automatically a smooth manifold.

Edit: To elaborate a bit more: A Lie group has more structure than a smooth manifold, it has the extra group structure. So given a topological manifold, proving that it's a Lie group is an overkill if you just want to prove it's a smooth manifold. Lie group = smooth manifold + group.

It may be that OP hasn't learned the most general definition of Lie groups, like the one contained in Brian Hall's Lie groups & representations book, where he begins by defining a Lie group as a subgroup of the general linear group, but please be aware this the general linear group is already a smooth manifold hence this definition of Lie group already implicitly assumes a smooth manifold structure.

Comment: The question of the OP suggests that the definitions are unclear, so I would be more precise: A (smooth) Lie group is not a smooth manifold, but given a Lie group we obtain a smooth manifold by removing the group operation from the given data.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the statement "a Lie group is not a smooth manifold", since being a smooth manifold is part of the definition of being a Lie group.

Comment: $$\text{Lie group = set + smooth manifold structure + group structure}$$Saying that a Lie group is a smooth manifold is like saying that a Lie group is a group (we all say that and that's okay as long as we remember that what we actually mean is that a Lie group **without its smooth manifold structure** is a group...)

Comment: I feel like this is semantics at this point. To me, if a thing is x and y then in particular it is x and in particular it is also y.

Comment: See also this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1606915/532409