# Is $\mathbb{P}^1$ a group scheme?

Tags: schemes, projective-schemes, group-schemes

It's known that the set of meromorphic functions (functions to $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$) on a complex variety $X$ forms a field, called the function field of $X$.

**Edit**: Thanks to the comment by @Qiaochu Yuan, I realize that $\mathbb{PC}^1(X)\neq$ the set of meromorphic functions, since we don't allow the constant function with constant value $\infty$ to be meromorphic.

So is it possible that, as a scheme over $\mathbb{C}$, the projective line $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$ is a group scheme?

What if $\mathbb{C}$ is replaced by a general field $K$ or even $\mathbb{Z}$?

(I have never seen an explicit projective group scheme of the form $\mathop{\mathrm{Proj}}S$ in any reference, i.e. stating the multiplication morphism. All explicit examples introducing the group schemes are the affine ones. Hence stating any projective group scheme of the form $\mathop{\mathrm{Proj}}S$ while stating the multiplication morphism in the comment or answer will be nice)

Comment: What is the relevance of the first paragraph to your question?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan It means that $\mathbb{CP}^1(X)$ is a field and in particular a group. Hence it is possible that $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}(X)$ is a group when $X$ is considered as a scheme.

Comment: A field is not a group! It has a zero element. To form a field we also need to exclude the constant function with constant value $\infty$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan the addition part makes it a group. I just checked wiki again.

Comment: Then why mention that it's a field? In any case you still need to exclude the constant function with constant value $\infty$. So this is not a group-valued representable functor which I assume is what you had in mind.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Well, I didn't remember the part of excluding constant $\infty$ function, that's my bad. Now it looks like the first paragraph is indeed wrong. I will edit it now.

Comment: The argument had to be wrong, because if it were correct $\mathbb{CP}^1$ would have to be a group object! But at least now I understand the motivation you had in mind; to be clear I think this is a natural question to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. A stronger statement is true: $S^2 \cong \mathbb{CP}^1$ is not a topological group. There are several different ways to see this and you can check out e.g. [this math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829928/can-s2-be-turned-into-a-topological-group/829997#829997) for details. Here it would suffice to prove the weaker claim that $S^2$ is not a Lie group, which can be done using the [hairy ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem) or by classifying $2$-dimensional Lie algebras. A general fact which implies this conclusion at-a-glance is that if a compact triangulable path-connected space admits a topological group structure then by the [Lefschetz fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_fixed-point_theorem) it must have Euler characteristic $0$ (or be a point).

**Edit:** Actually for the desired statement it suffices to show that $\mathbb{CP}^1$ is not a complex Lie group which is even easier and can be done by classifying $1$-dimensional complex Lie algebras. There's only one, namely $\mathbb{C}$, so $\mathbb{C}$ is the unique simply connected $1$-dimensional complex Lie group.

Examples of projective group schemes are given by [elliptic curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve) and more generally by [abelian varieties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_variety). The group operation is a bit annoying to write down explicitly but [very classical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#The_group_law). Somewhat surprisingly they are all abelian, hence the name; see e.g. Lemma 39.9.5 in [the Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BF9).

In the complex analytic category elliptic curves are quotients $\mathbb{C}/\Gamma$ where $\Gamma$ is a lattice in $\mathbb{C}$, as they would have to be to be compatible with the above-mentioned argument about $1$-dimensional complex Lie groups and Lie algebras.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Maybe you want to add that the analytification functor respects terminal object and product hence group objects, so if $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ is a group scheme, then its analytification $\mathbb{CP}^1=\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathbb{C})$ is a group object in the category of complex analytic spaces, and hence a topological group. Then it follows from your argument that it cann't be a topological group. I want to add that because I personally didn't know why it follows from your argument at first and so it would be nice to clear it out.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Actually for this conclusion, as your argument suggests, it would suffice to show that $\mathbb{CP}^1$ can't be a complex Lie group; I've edited in details.